# How to set a custom number field to default to 0

Tags: default-value

I would like to set a custom number field to default to 0 as the default value. I tried entering 0 on the default formula editor and even tried 1*0 as the default value of the number field. I am always getting a null. How do i make a number field to default to 0? I am stumped
Buyan

Comment: It works for me...can you post some code that is not working? A concise unit test could be illustrative.

Comment: Works as expected for me as well. How are you creating the record? Apex? Standard Detail page?

Answer (score 2):

One mechanism of creating a new record with the default values in Apex is to use the `Schema.SObjectType.newSObject()` method and specify that you want the instance created with the defaults (field values & Record Type).

The first parameter is the RecordType Id and the second parameter indicates if default values should be set for its custom fields.

```
// Create an account with predefined default values
Account acct = (Account)Account.sObjectType.newSObject(null, true);
// Provide a value for Name
acct.Name = 'Acme';
// Insert new account
insert acct;
```

Documentation: [SObjectType Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_SObjectType.htm#apex_Schema_SObjectType_newSObject_3)